# RestAngular get array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to get JSON response from server using restangular.

```
  var baseAccounts = Restangular.one('getAllCustomers');
  baseAccounts.getList().then(function(customers) {
      $scope.myData = customers;
      console.log(customers);
    });
```

The problem is that I always get the response in following format:

```
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
addRestangularMethod: function bound() {
all: function bound() {
allUrl: function bound() {
clone: function bound() {
customDELETE: function bound() {
customGET: function bound() {
customGETLIST: function bound() {
```

But I would like only structure of pure returned JSON. If could somebody put here example for RestAngular plugin I would be very glad.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

To make things simple you can use Restangular 1.4 and chain the plain() function on the response

```
baseAccounts.getList().then(function(customers){
 $scope.myDate = customers.plain();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var baseAccounts = Restangular.one('getAllCustomers');
  baseAccounts.getList().then(function(response) {
      $scope.myData = response.customers;
      console.log(response.customers);
    });
```

Comment: undefined. 

Structure is here:
http://www.inorthwind.com/Service1.svc/getAllCustomers

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for an answer to this. I have not found anything better, so I implemented that way.

```
  var baseAccounts = Restangular.one('getAllCustomers');      
  baseAccounts.getList().then(function(customers) {
    var tmp = [];
    customers.forEach(function(element){
      tmp.push(element);
    });

  $scope.myData = tmp;
  console.log(customers);
});
```

then the return will be

```
 0: Object
 1: Object
 2: Object
```